# Open QFile for appending

Tags: c++, file, qt, qfile

How can I open a QFile for appending, i.e. the equivalent of

```
FILE *f = fopen("myfile.txt", "a");
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Open the file in `QIODevice::Append` mode:

```
QFile f(...);
if (f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append)) {
  ...
}
```

See also the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open-1).

Comment: The Qt documentation is misleading:

"The mode must be QIODevice::ReadOnly, QIODevice::WriteOnly, or QIODevice::ReadWrite. It may also have additional flags, such as QIODevice::Text and QIODevice::Unbuffered."

QIODevice documentation mentions the Append flag, but it not apparent from just looking at the QFile documentation.