# Qt C++ Continuing a File and not Overwriting

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a program in Qt C++ to create a sort of database. However, whenever I hit the push button it overwrites the entire file instead of continuing to a new line like I need it to do. I would really appreciate any info on how to fix this.

Relevant Code Portion:

```
QFile file("C:/Users/brandan/Desktop/GUIPrograms/Kumon.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
QTextStream stream(&file); //stream of information
stream << " " << endl;
stream << name << " " << month << " " << day << " " << year << " " << page << endl;
file.close();
```

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open QFile for appending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856734/open-qfile-for-appending)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to open the file in *append mode*:

```
file.open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text);
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `QIODevice::Append`?

By the way, this has been asked a several times. A simple google search gives this:
[Open QFile for appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856734/open-qfile-for-appending)